# Magento MMD Product Warranty Registration Required Field Removal

Tags: php, magento

I purchased and installed the MMD Product Warranty Extension for Magento.

I want to remove the required fields from the Product Register Form (register.phtml).

I've tried to remove the class="Required"
and the required-entry in the class="input-text **required-entry**" as some Magento tutorials have mentioned. No luck!

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED!

1) Edit the Controller... app > code > local > MMD > Productwarranty > controllers > RegisterController.php

The example below removes the required field from the TITLE dropdown. Do this for all fields you wish to not be required.

inside RegisterController.php look for:

```
if (!Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['title']) , 'NotEmpty')) {$error = true;}
```

Change to:

```
if (!Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['title']) , 'NotEmpty')) {$error = false;}
```

**Note** It's good practice to remove the class="required" and any required-entry from any class="input-text required-entry" you dont want required on the Register.phtml file.